# Python3.8 - How To get total combinations which can be made with min length and max length

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-itertools, word-list

I am actually making a tool which takes **minimum length & maximum length and then characters** to use and then in the given criteria it **writes every possible combination to a wordlist**, but is there a way to get how many combinations can be made using Min Length, Max length & Characters

My Code is:

```
import itertools

min_len = int(input("Min Len: "))
max_len = int(input("Max Len: "))
characters = str(input("Characters To use: "))

for n in range(min_len, max_len + 1):
    for xs in itertools.product(characters, repeat=n):
        word = ''.join(xs)
        print(f"Writing {word}")
```

**I Am On Python3.8, Linux**

Thanks For Helping In Advance!

Comment: To be clear, you just want to know the *number of* combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given `w` characters, you can create `w**n` strings of length `n`.  So you're looking for `w**min_length + ......  + w**max_length`

Answer (score 1):

This code will work...

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
min_len = int(input("Min Len: "))
max_len = int(input("Max Len: "))
characters = str(input("Characters To use: "))
combination = list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(characters, i) for i in range(min_len, max_len+1)))
for comb in combination:
    print("".join(comb))
```